# Index out of range while loading data from Sqlite DB in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using Core Data and SQLite DB. My code **worked normally** until two days ago. I didn't change any code or database names but it still triggers an error that it can't load data from the database. Here's my code on how I create the persistent container in the App Delegate.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Milionater")

    let storeUrl = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Nafsyaki.sqlite")

    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    description.url = storeUrl

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

And here's the function which is loading data from the database.

```
mutating func loadData() {
    
    let predicateLevel = NSPredicate(format: "level == \(currentLevel)")
    
    let request: NSFetchRequest<MainTable> = MainTable.fetchRequest()
    
    request.predicate = predicateLevel
    
    do {
        self.arr = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error loading categories \(error)")
    }
```

[image]

I've tried to clean the Build Folder, Derived Data, change GIT version but nothing helps.
When I ran the app on iPhone SE 2 and iPhone 8 app worked normally, in all other devices it showed the same error but when I updated my Xcode it stopped working in that 2 devices.

Comment: What is the value of currentLevel when loadData() is called?

Comment: So you fetch no longer returns any data, have you verified there is still any data in the db? Did you rename anything or did some other changes that might jave caused Core Data to create a new database file? Or to follow up on what @Magnas wrote, what happens if you run the fetch without the predicate?

Comment: The value of currentLevel is 1. And yes I have tried it but it triggers the same error.

Comment: I think it isn't code problem because I have tried to change GIT version(that version works normally) but it shows the same error.

Comment: How do you trigger the population of the db with entities? If the db has somehow been emptied or maybe run on a new simulator the persistent store may simply remain empty after creation?

Comment: Did you actually verify that there is data in the db using some other tool? You haven't answered this question yet and frankly there is not enough information here for us to properly help you.

Comment: I right-click on db and choose "Show in Finder", it shows true place for it. There are 380 rows in that table. I understand you, I'm trying to show you all the details.

Comment: Maybe turning on Core Data debugging could help you, see [this article](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/core-data-debugging-xcode/)

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson you helped me a lot. I read that article and saw that db path is: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3D353F53-A384-4E85-834B-90DC39A82011/data/Containers/Data/Application/00943128-3B0C-46B6-A6C5-3D2B1555A506/Documents/Nafsyaki.sqlite. Which exists but it's empty. Do you know why it's creating a new(empty) one?

Comment: No not really but maybe the Xcode upgrade is involved.

Comment: Also, you should refactor that function so it doesn't crash the app if the array is empty.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it, but now everything works fine in the simulator, but in a physical device, it crashes(Database is empty). :)